# configure: DX_INIT_DOXYGEN check status

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, configure, m4

Is there any way to check the status of `DX_INIT_DOXYGEN`?

This macro from https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_doxygen.html

Answer (score 0):

```
AS_IF([test "x$with_docs_only" == xyes],
      [AS_IF([DX_TEST_FEATURE(doc) && DX_TEST_FEATURE(html) &&
              DX_TEST_FEATURE(man) && DX_TEST_FEATURE(pdf)],
             [AS_MESSAGE([=====SUCCESS=====])],
             [AC_MSG_ERROR([=====FAILURE=====])])])
```

It can be done by using `DX_TEST_FETURE` macro (see example above) from `ax_prog_doxygen` that checks whether some tools are available or not.
In this example, it checks doxygen, html, man and pdf tools.